# a couple questions regarding assembly signatures in .net core

Tags: .net-core, .net-assembly, sign

I understand the concept behind signing code, but is the signature in a .net core assembly signing the code as well or just some description of the assembly? I read about something called authenticode and I'm not really sure what it is.

What I am trying to achieve is to make sure that some assemblies I provide to a 3rd party can't be tampered with.

When signing the assembly, I have a check box called "Public Sign" that I do not understand (I'm using Rider); what is it for?

Also, do I need the assembly to self check its signature? or will it not load if the signature is invalid? (I don't control the host btw)

Comment: can the person that voted to close this comment why?

Comment: [The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/assembly/strong-named) are pretty extensive. Authenticode is [something else](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/install/authenticode), mostly used by drivers (although it's available for regular executables as well) and not exposed through .NET client tools. As the docs note, signing is not a security feature -- you can prevent a modified assembly from being loaded into an executable, for example, but that in itself will not prevent someone who can do that from modifying the executable to allow a new assembly.